# Is it possible to subscribe to event subscriptions in C#?

Tags: c#, events

If I have an event like this:

```
public delegate void MyEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e);
public event MyEventHandler MyEvent;
```

And adds an eventhandler like this:

```
MyEvent += MyEventHandlerMethod;
```

... is it then possible to register this somehow? In other words - is it possible to have something like:

```
MyEvent.OnSubscribe += MySubscriptionHandler;
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Similar to auto-implemented properties, events are auto-implemented by default as well.

You can expand the declaration of an `event` as follows:

```
public event MyEventHandler MyEvent
{
    add
    {
        ...
    }
    remove
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

See, for example, [How to: Use a Dictionary to Store Event Instances (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z4ka55h8.aspx)

See [Events get a little overhaul in C# 4, Part I: Locks](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cburrows/archive/2010/03/05/events-get-a-little-overhaul-in-c-4-part-i-locks.aspx) for how auto-implemented events differ between C# 3 and C# 4.

Answer (score 6):

It is possible to declare the event accessors specifically, i.e., the add and remove accessors.

Doing so makes it possible to do custom logic when new event handlers are added.

Answer (score 1):

When you define your events, you can actually use the longer format to execute more code when people attach or remove themselves from your events.

Check out the info on the [add](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc713648.aspx) and [remove](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc713642.aspx) keywords.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible if you declare your custom event, like this *pseudocode*:

```
class MyClass
{


    public event EventHandler MyEvent
    {
        add    {     //someone subscribed to this event  ! }
        remove {     //someone unsubscribed from this event ! }
    }


    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess, you are looking for event accessors. Way to customizing the references to the subscribers. Here is how you can do it

```
public class TestClass
{

   private event EventHandler UnderlyingEvent;
   public event EventHandler TestEvent
   {
        add
        {
             UnderlyingEvent += value;
        }
        remove
        {
             UnderlyingEvent -= value;
        }
   }
}
```

For more information, please visit this article

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163533.aspx