# Is there an event for when an event gets/loses listeners?

Tags: c#, events, .net-3.5

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to subscribe to event subscriptions in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10483935/is-it-possible-to-subscribe-to-event-subscriptions-in-c)

Searching for information about event events isn't easy. I'm just hoping that it's not because it can't be done. I'm just hoping that the answer is "there's an event for that," or some other means.

I'm dealing with an event where listening for the event is comparatively expensive. (A watch has to be put upon it in another system which I'm tying into, involving keeping track of which things to keep track of and COM overhead.)

Therefore, I don't really want to be watching for the event unless I know that something wants it.

The simple way of doing it is like this:

```
public class MyThing
{
    public delegate void MyEventHandler(object sender, MyEventArgs ea);
    public event MyEventHandler Change;

    public void StartWatching()
    {
        ...
    }

    public void StopWatching()
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

This is used in this manner:

```
var thing = new MyThing();
thing.Change += this.thing_Change
thing.StartWatching();

thing.Change -= this.thing_Change
thing.StopWatching();  // Hopefully nothing else is watching...
```

But this isn't as elegant as I'd like. I could do it with replacing `thing.Change += x` with `thing.StartWatching(x)`, which would then start watching, and the converse would check if `Change == null`, but I'd like it if it could be done with the full elegance of the event model.

Comment: Typical... after hunting for ages, looking down the "related" questions on the side, I spot [Is it possible to subscribe to event subscriptions in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10483935/is-it-possible-to-subscribe-to-event-subscriptions-in-c) Someone needs to make a full-text search engine which lets you write *paragraphs* rather than *words*.

Comment: Yo dawg, I heard you like events, so I put an event in your event so you can listen while you listen.

Comment: @ChrisMorgan That's happened to me a few times on terms that generate a huge amount of noise when searching. No worries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a [custom event accessor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882534.aspx) might be what you are looking for.

```
int count = 0;

event EventHandler MyThing.Change
{
    add
    {
        lock (Change)
        {
            if (count == 0)
            {
                StartWatching();
            }

            count++;
            Change += value;
        }
    }
    remove
    {
        lock (Change)
        {
            count--;
            if (count == 0)
            {
                StopWatching();
            }

            Change -= value;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to declare you event as property and use add/remove accessors

```
class YourClass
{
    public event EventHandler<EventArgs>  MyEvent
    {
        add
        {
            // Add new subscriber code here
        }

        remove
        {
            // Remove subscriber code here
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can override the add/remove methods for the event and do the work there.

```
public class MyThing
{
    public delegate void MyEventHandler(object sender, MyEventArgs ea);

    private MyEventHandler _change;
    public event MyEventHandler Change
    {
       add 
      { 
          var previousChange = _change;
          _change += value; 
          if (previousChange == null)
          {
             StartWatching();
          }
       }
       remove 
       { 
          _change -= value;
          if (_change == null) 
          {
             StopWatching();
          }
       }
    }

    public void StartWatching()
    {
        ...
    }

    public void StopWatching()
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Currently, this is not thread-safe but you can easily make it so.